# ionic 3 importing font for every device

Tags: css, ionic-framework, fonts, ionic3, font-face

I have a simple project on ionic 3, i just need to use a custom font in an input on the app.

I copied the font (ttf format) to "../assets/fonts"

in css;

```
font-family: license plate, ariel, sans-serif;
```

just added this.

Now its ok when i serve the app with ionic serve and open it in chrome it works fine. (font already installed on my windows) But with ionicDevApp i cant see the font in actual iphone.

how can i import font ? couldnt fine any official ionic document about it and in  similar stackoverflow topics are very complicated to understand.

i want to see that font in every device my app installed.

Please assist me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly my area of expertise, but we use the Noto Hero font this way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hero';
  src: url('Hero.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('Hero.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;  
}
```

So I guess you are missing the url and src part.

Comment: To where variables.scss or page’s scss ?

Comment: We placed it in app.scss (actually it's a separate hero.scss file which is imported in app.scss)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. But i havent got any scss file of my font. I just have ttf. Besides whats in that file ?

Comment: the font.scss file contains the snippet I posted in my answer. It is not necessary to put in another file, you can write it just in your app.scss.